# Why do I need to use "as" keyword in this sql query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL query:

```
select top(1) 
    salary 
from 
    (select top(2) salary 
     from employee 
     order by salary desc) as b 
order by 
    salary asc
```

If I don't utilize `as b` it will give me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ...

Why is mandatory to use `as` in this query?

Comment: The answers (and the voters) on this question are all over the place. The answer is simply that SQL Server requires all derived tables to be given an alias.  The error message is very unclear though.

Comment: One more thing, you can use `min(salary)` instead of `top(1) salary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `as` keyword.  In fact, I advise using `as` for column aliases but not for table aliases.  So, I would write this as:

```
select top(1) salary
from (select top(2) salary 
      from employee 
      order by salary desc
     ) b
order by salary asc;
```

You do need the table alias for the subquery, because SQL Server requires that all subqueries in the `from` clause be named.

Answer (score 3):

This is TSql syntax. Subquery in FROM must have an alias even it's never used. Oracle for example considers this alias optional.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a sub-query that, according to [the Transact-SQL documentation on `FROM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx), makes the use of an alias mandatory:

> When a derived table, rowset or table-valued function, or operator clause (such as `PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT`) is used, the **required** *table_alias* at the end of the clause is the associated table name for all columns, including grouping columns, returned.

Note that with *derived table* the kind of sub-query is intended that you use in your SQL statement:

> *derived_table*
>   Is a subquery that retrieves rows from the database. *derived_table* is used as input to the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using 'salary' twice. Without an alias the interpreter won't know what 'salary' to order the results by. By using an alias it can discern between employee.salary and b.salary.

Comment: No way to refer to `employee` directly in SELECT of the OP query

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two queries. The first one selects the top 2 salaries from employee. You are calling this list "b". Then you are selecting the top salary from "b".

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to get the 2nd highest salary...  as if you need the 3rd or 4th you're approach would get much more challenging...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT salary, row_number() over (order by salary desc)  rn
      FROM  employee) E
WHERE rn = 2
```